# Interrupt not supported

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I'm using the emulator (emu8086). I need to know if it is possible, through an alternative way to use (interrupts) that the program does not support?

I'm trying to debug the MBR and there are some interrupts the program does not support. Tips???

Comment: Use a different emulator such as bochs or qemu. Or, if you have to use emu8086 then obviously don't use the unsupported interrupts.

Comment: Or just write code for a real processor.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if the emulator does not support emulating the interrupt, there is no way around it. You will need to use a different emulator such as bochs or qemu, as Jester suggested.